# How to use Standard Deviation and Mean

Tags: statistics, means, standard-deviation

I have the following population

```
| Amounts |
|---------|
| 3022.03 |
| 3870.91 |
| 2796.78 |
| 5104.81 |
| 3413.48 |
| 4409.38 |
| 7265.16 |
| 2396    |
| 827.73  |
| 653.83  |
| 1072.73 |
| 231.28  |
| 112.47  |
| 672.16  |
| 264.52  |
| 213.97  |
| 2034.23 |
| 2660.1  |
| 879.87  |
| 1234.62 |
| 1334.81 |
| 729.68  |
| 507.21  |
| 312.49  |
| 412.72  |
| 317.11  |
| 143.34  |
| 79.34   |
| 20.14   |
| 36.39   |
| 29.25   |
| 209.39  |
| 385.88  |
| 273.69  |
| 360.87  |
| 85.24   |
| 33.09   |
| 20.26   |
| 3.7     |
| 5.51    |
| 10.12   |
| 5.08    |
```

The mean is 1153.60 and the Standard Deviation 1649.15

The numbers within one Standard Deviation (around 70% of the cases) should be between 1153.60+1649.15=2802.75 (max) and  1153.60-1649.15=-495.55 (min) but -495.55 is a negative number.

What am I missing out?

Comment: You seem to be assuming a normal distribution, but have no reason to do so.

Comment: @Henry Ok, in this case, I suppose I should use another method. What do you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

You could find $a$ and $b$ where
$$
\hat{F}(a) \approx \frac{1 - 0.70}{2} = 0.15
\qquad \text{and} \qquad
\hat{F}(b) \approx 1 - \frac{1 - 0.70}{2} = 0.85
$$
and $\hat{F}$ is the [empirical distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function).
Note that this does not make any guarantees about the [data generating distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_generating_process).
Here is some Python code that computes it for your data, stored in the variable `values`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.quantile(values, 0.15), np.quantile(values, 0.85)
(29.825999999999997, 2776.2780000000002)
```

Alternatively, you could assume a parametric model for the data generating distribution.
For example, if you assume it is a [log-normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution), then you can estimate the interval by a method of your choosing. Indeed, this is what you did above but you made the assumption of a normal distribution (arguably a bad assumption).

Comment: @ parsiad how should I interpret "(a)≈"? Apologies but I have never studied Statistics

Comment: @piopio: I think it's better if you go through an introductory book in statistics. $\hat{F}$ is a function (see the Wikipedia link) and it is being evaluated at $a$. $\approx$ means approximately equal to.